# How to set json headers accept and content-type to a URL in a Script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a URL that calls an API which returns a json response but the request going out doesn't have the correct headers for some reason.

The URL is inside the src property of a `script` tag.

**How can I add the headers back in to set the `content-type` and `accept` header?**

Since I'm not doing an AJAX call or a get request implicitly could I still do this?

Comment: you need to use cors+ajax for that, or move the config info from headers to queryString parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place headers in script tags.

If your API is on the same domain, you can do an Ajax Request with JSON as a data type.

If not, my advice would be that you create a proxy on your servers that cURL to your API.

In both these scenarios, you will be able to send proper headers with your calls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, but do you get response as string? I have had that kind of problems some so downloaded a json.js from json.org and converted response string to json.

```
var var1 = '{json string here}'; 
var result = JSON.parse(var1);
```

Comment: Thanks for editing. Im using mobile phone so unable to style my text.